# Which files on my website aren't being accessed, using Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

Based on people accessing my site, how do I see which files are not being viewed by visitors (because no inbound links or otherwise)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save accessed files:

```
zcat -f /var/log/httpd/*access* | grep -o "GET [^ ?]\+" | cut -c 5- | sort -u > /tmp/accessedfiles
```

Save existing files:

```
(cd /var/www/vhosts/SITE/; find) | sort -u | cut -c2- > /tmp/existingfiles
```

Set subtract:

```
comm /tmp/accessedfiles /tmp/existingfiles -1 -3
```